# Determine $p$ for which the hyperharmonic sequence $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^p}$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm asked to determine $p \in \mathbb{R} $ for which the hyperharmonic series:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^p}$$ is convergent.

I started using the Ratio Test, which gives me:
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{k \to \infty} \left| \frac{\frac{1}{(k + 1)^p}}{\frac{1}{k^p}} \right| \\
&= \lim_{k \to \infty} \left| \frac{k^p}{(k + 1)^p} \right| \\
&= \lim_{k \to \infty} \left| \left(\frac{k}{k + 1}\right)^p \right|
\end{align}

But then I'm quite stuck. Anyone have any idea how I can continue?

Comment: Integral Test or Cauchy Condensation Test are the best options.

Comment: Never heard of Cauchy Condensation Test, so I'm taking a look at the Integral test now.

Comment: [*p-series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#P-series)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use integral test. 
$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^p}$ is convergent if and only if the improper integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^p}dx$ converges. 
Now, when you integrate the latter, you 'll see that it is possible when and only when $p>1$